# How to avoid some sites rejecting HTTP get using go

Tags: http, go

We have a script that on a daily basis checks all of the web links in all of our database records (the users want notifications when a link becomes out of date).

There are a couple of sites that work fine through a web browser from this IP address, but when fetched through GO, they either disconnect before completing the request or return a HTTP authorisation denied message.

I am assuming some sort of firewall (F5) is filtering/blocking the request. This occurs even when I change the HTTP request to use a common user agent. What can we do to ensure a GO request looks like a standard browser?

```
func fetch_url(url string, d time.Duration) (int, error) {

    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: d,
    }

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53")

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    status := resp.StatusCode
    resp.Body.Close()
    return status, nil
}
```

Comment: Try capturing a request from your web browser and setting your go HTTP client's headers to match.  It might be more than just the `User-Agent`...

Comment: At what rate do you fetch pages at?  If it is too quickly you may be blocked as well if you hit some sort of rate limiter.

Comment: Maybe they don't want your requests.

Comment: @mihai Actually they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try matching the exact headers from a request from your web browser to eliminate other factors.  A smart firewall could have heuristics on what looks like a web browser versus a robot.

Notice that the go http client sends only a minimal HTTP request:

```txt
GET /foo HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3030
User-Agent: Go 1.1 package http
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Whereas a web browser is more chatty:

```txt
GET /foo HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3030
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```